# Query table with unpredictable number of columns by BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Let's say, I have a table from log, it looks like this:
[Log Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08oXm.png)

I need a result table like:
[Result table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPQS4.png)

But the problem is my dataset is not only 7, but maybe 24, 100 value columns.
My query with 7 value columns is:

````
select 
*
from My_Dataset
unpivot 
(status for value in (value_1, value_2, value_3, value_4, value_5, value_6, value_7))```

But is there anyway to automatic this process for value_n?
Thank you.
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select id, arr[offset(1)] as value
from your_table t,
unnest(split(translate(to_json_string(t), '{}"', ''))) kv, 
unnest([struct(split(kv, ':') as arr)])
where starts_with(arr[offset(0)], 'value_')
```

if applied to sample data in your question (i used only three value_N columns but it works for any!)

[image]

Another option (maybe less verbose and simpler to swallow)

```
select id, val
from your_table t, unnest([to_json_string(t)]) json,
unnest(`bqutil.fn.json_extract_keys`(json)) col with offset 
join unnest(`bqutil.fn.json_extract_values`(json)) val with offset 
using(offset)
where starts_with(col, 'value_')
```

obviously with same output as above first option

Answer (score 2):

It's possible via SQL scripting.

You have to get a column list of your table first and save it in variable. Then call dynamic query with `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`

```
DECLARE field_list STRING;

SET field_list = ((
    SELECT STRING_AGG(column_name) FROM `my_project_id`.my_dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE column_name LIKE "value_%" AND table_name = 'my_table'
));

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE "SELECT id, SPLIT(value, '_')[OFFSET(1)] value FROM  my_dataset.my_table UNPIVOT (status FOR value IN ("||field_list||"))"
```